# What are the troubleshooting steps for a blank screen during a windows 8 install?

Tags: installation, windows-8-preview

When I boot from USB it shows the progress bar loading files then sits at a blank screen.

The steps I've followed so far are:

- Boot from the USB on another machine to verify I can get further. Try
- Use a different image (I've tried the x64 with developer tools and x86)
- Remove any other input devices (Keyboard/Mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably talk with Microsoft regarding this as Windows 8 is not yet a released final product. Any bugs/installation issues should be brought up to them as it's still in a beta state.

Alternatively, try doing a md5check sum on the ISOs that you have downloaded to make sure that they're not corrupted.

Also, try to install using a DVD to see if you get different results.

Comment: Burning a DVD of the x86 image fixed the problem.